# php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] is returning different to document.URL in a php file giving javascript headers

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this code to make a php file become a javascript file

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
?>
```

Within the file, I need to get the document's url in both javascript and php.

Javascript returns the URL of the page, but PHP returns the URL of the script.

How can I force PHP to return the URL of the page?

My PHP `echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];`
My JS    `var url = document.URL`

Comment: `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` might do the job - although it's not 100% reliable - but then, there is often no point in having a dynamic JS file in the first place. All it does is put unnecessary strain on the server. Are you sure the dynamic parts can't be done in the main HTML file, while serving the main JavaScript (the part that is never going to change) as a static file?

Comment: im very sure @Pekka웃 this is a javascript file intended to be on external pages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url may help